# Question re: Collatz Conjecture

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, collatz-conjecture

Disclaimer: I'm not a mathematician and for the most part I do not understand what, exactly, it takes to mathematically prove anything. That is where this question comes from.

Why can't the Collatz Conjecture be proven by showing that all even numbers less than 11 do "resolve" (via the collatz division and multiplication) to 1. From there, couldn't it be shown that all even numbers have a <del>multiple</del> factor that is less than 10, thus proving the case for starting with an even number? Which just leaves the odd-numbered case. But for odd numbers, mulitplying by 3 and adding one always results in an even number, which can be proven to resolve to 1 via the even numbered part of the proof.

Obviously I'm missing something but i don't have the words and labels to say what it is to investigate further.

I apologize in advance if this question doesn't belong on this SE and thank you in advance for any insight.

EDIT: I haven't actually thought about this in a little while before writing it up here and have obviously goofed in a couple of spots.
One thing to correct is that every even number has a factor that is of the form `2^x` and that any number `2^x` resolves to 1 in a straight line.

Comment: "all even numbers have a multiple that is less than 10" ? Taken literally, that is obviously wrong, so you must mean something different.

Comment: @Ted, sorry. I meant factor, not multiple.

Comment: @Ramy: well, all even numbers by definition have a factor less than $10$, namely $2$, but what does that have to do with the Collatz conjecture? I think you mean to ask that iterating the Collatz map eventually hits a number less than $10$; if so, nobody knows how to do this and this sort of thing is what is actually difficult about the Collatz conjecture.

Comment: $62$ has a factor less than $10$. When you divide by $2$, you get $31$, which is prime. $3×31+1 = 94$, a larger even number than we started with. When divided by $2$ the result is $47$, which is an even bigger prime than $31$. This eventually stops, but it certainly doesn't look promising at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we knew that every Collatz orbit eventually hits a number less than $10$ (is that what you mean?) then we'd be done immediately. So we don't know that! More generally if we knew that every Collatz orbit eventually hits a number less than $N$ for *any* $N$ then we'd have reduced the Collatz conjecture to checking $N$ cases, and we'd be done as long as $N$ was not enormous; [apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Supporting_arguments) the conjecture has been verified up to $N = 2^{68}$ or so. We don't know this either! This is the entire difficulty of the problem.

In other words, despite having verified the conjecture up to $N = 2^{68}$, for all we know it's possible that some extremely large number has a Collatz orbit that never dips below, say, $2^{100}$, and so would be a counterexample we haven't tested computationally yet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think what I don't understand is that, if we know the first ten numbers all resolve to 1, then any number that resolves to those numbers must resolve to one, and any number that resolves to those numbers must resolve to one, etc etc. And if that's the case, how can there exist a number that does not hit one of those orbits eventually? And it's not just that every even number has a factor below 10. It's that every even number has a factor that is 2^x. And any number 2^x inherently resolves to 1.

Comment: You seem to think that repeatedly applying Collatz to a number $n$ must eventually lead to one of its factors. There is no reason I can see for this.

Comment: @Ramy: well, just try to prove it! What is stopping a number from just staying really big forever? The Collatz map makes a number a little more than $3$ times bigger whenever it's odd; if this happens, say, a third of the time on average, then it'll just keep getting bigger forever. You need to show that the $3x + 1$ case doesn't occur too often and this precisely what we don't know how to show. I have no idea what you're trying to say about the factors.

Comment: Ty, @QiaochuYuan. My question is why would a number stay really big forever? Every number will either be halved or halved on the next step. My theory is that eventually, every even number works its way to a power of 2 and all powers of 2 are proven to resolve. Primes are the only wrinkle IMO. The only way (I think) permanent growth could happen is if there are a series of prime numbers whose triple + 1 is double another prime number. Anyway, I've marked your answer correct but, honestly, I just want to have a discussion about ways to approach this proof. This is not the right forum for that.

Comment: @Ramy: yes, of course the numbers end up getting halved, the question is how often this occurs compared to the $3x + 1$ case as I just said. There is nothing special about primes as far as I know, the question is how often or how little we end up dividing by $2$. Maybe these slides by Terence Tao will be helpful: https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2020/02/collatz.pdf